# Using Session to limit form submission by time

Tags: php

I have spent over 2 hours scouring the net trying to figure this out. I am trying to stop multiple form submission any faster than 60 seconds. Here is what I am using.

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['last_submit']))
    $_SESSION['last_submit'] = time();

if (time()-$_SESSION['last_submit'] < 60)
    die('Post limit exceeded. Please wait at least 60 seconds');
else
    $_SESION['last_submit'] = time();
```

I found this bit here on the site but haven't been able to figure anything else out as far as getting it to work. I have this bit of code on my page at the beginning that does the DB query with the previous pages POST results. Do I need to set `$last_submit` to a certain value? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide some more details: How do you use this code and what exactly works different from what you're expecting?

Comment: I believe that code works as expected, you should just set `$_SESSION['last_submit'] = 1` when someone submit your form.

Comment: @MihaiIorga no? because he is setting it to `time()` ?

Comment: uhmm ... good eyes :), I don't know why I saw that as a different variable

Comment: open brace after the `else`, write your code and close the brace.

Comment: @air4x his code is perfectly valid (syntax wise).

Comment: @vanneto I meant he could write his form processing logic within the `else` condition. But of course as he is using `die` in the `if`, that is not necessary.

Comment: code looks perfectly fine, should do what you expect. in which way  it does not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two problems. Firstly, on the first execution you are setting the session value to `time()`, so the first try will always produce the limit exceeded error. The second problem is you have a typo in `$_SESION`.

Try:

```
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['last_submit']) && time()-$_SESSION['last_submit'] < 60)
    die('Post limit exceeded. Please wait at least 60 seconds');
else
    $_SESSION['last_submit'] = time();
```

Also it should be noted that is this not foolproof because users can refuse cookies or delete the session cookie, in order to bypass your check.

Comment: You nailed it! That bit of code works perfectly. I understand it can be gotten around but I am not knowledgeable enough yet to try to attempt anything better. I have a honeypot set up and this plus the JEXEC to help stop injection attacks. Hopefully it will do until I get better. I am trying to beat php/mysql into my brain. Sure is alot different than the basic I used with  my C=64 back in the day. One question though is there a set of variables that are set when I call a session start? Just curious. Also is there a noobs guide to understanding php/mysql security you know of? Thanks again

Comment: If they stop the session then when I grab their ID from session like this '$user = JFactory::getUser();' 
'$cf_user_id = $user->get('id');' The user_id has to be over 40 so if I set an if statement $cf_user_id < 40 then die wouldn't that stop trying with no session?

Comment: If you mean the `$_SESSION` array then no, it will only contain what you populate it with yourself, no other values will be set automatically in that. Initialising a session though, will give you access to for example `session_id()` which will return the current user's session ID. If you are using Joomla then you don't need to call session_start() it will already be called by Joomla.

Comment: sorry was editing that comment while you were answering. Yes I am using joomla. Was just wondering if I could be tricky and do it like that to make it more secure from spamming

Comment: The Joomla user ID will be `0` unless they login, so you can't rely on it unless of course your form requires that user's are logged in. If you want to see if they are logged in you can look at the user ID and also `$user->guest` will be false.

Comment: yes the form is only accessible to registered and logged in users. So if they try to get out of the session inbetween the form and my code that actually queries this value would be 0. Sound like a good idea?

Comment: There is still a way around it. Suppose the user submits your form, then logs out, then logs back in (they will have a new session) and they can submit the form again before the 60 seconds is up. It depends how far you want to go with it. The only way to ensure it it can't be bypassed would be to store the last_submit time with the user in the db, then when they login, read it into the session. Using that, no amount of cookie deleting/logging in or out can bypass it. They could of course keep registering new accounts and submitting :)

Comment: wow! I didn't even think of that. I don't think(or hope) anyone would try that hard but you never know. Thank you for the info it is golden =] Have a good one.

Answer (score 2):

The last statement:

`$_SESION['last_submit'] = time();`

should be:

`$_SESSION['last_submit'] = time();`

You forgot an *S*...

Also this piece of code will *die* meaning that the `die` statement will be executed.

Alternative:

```
if (time() - ( isset($_SESSION['last_submit'])?$_SESSION['last_submit']:0 )< 60) 
    die('Post limit exceeded. Please wait at least 60 seconds'); 

// update the session
$_SESSION['last_submit'] = time();
```