# Limit form submission by time

Tags: php

I would like to limit the number of times a user can submit a form within a certain time limit. I understand that users can refuse cookies or delete the session, however that doesn't bother me.

I have the following code, from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815411/using-session-to-limit-form-submission-by-time) which is almost perfect:

```
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['last_submit']) && time()-$_SESSION['last_submit'] < 60)
    die('Post limit exceeded. Please wait at least 60 seconds');
else
$_SESSION['last_submit'] = time();
```

The issue I have is that it appears to be running on page load, not on the submission of the form.

- Where it is working - If I load the page form.php only once, then submit and return to form.php it works correctly and provides the post limit exceeded message.
- Where it is not working - If I load form.php, then refresh the page or load the page again it tells me post limit exceeded. This is not the case as the user has not submitted the form yet, only refreshed the page.

Is it possible to link the code with the form submission, so the user can reload the page as many times as they like, and the post limit exceeded message will only be returned after the form has actually been submitted?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: PHP code will only work on page load because it is server side. if you want to execute php code in real time, you'll need to use an AJAX call though javascript. wrap that in a javascript function and you can bind it to the form submitting so it only fires when the form is submitted (either using a submit button or hitting the enter key)

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement you can check for a required post value. If it exists, then it is a submit not a reload.

Something like:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['last_submit']) && time()-$_SESSION['last_submit'] < 60 
    && $_POST['foo'] != ''){
//....
```